# Unable to play sound via URL in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've looked and applied almost all the solutions given on StackOverflow but it is not working for me. Here is my code:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3"];
        NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

        [_player play];
```

Based on other answers in similar questions I've also made `@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;` but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Based on a comment I've also tried this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3"];
        AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url];
        AVPlayer *pla = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:item];
        [pla play];
```

But still it's not playing!

Comment: AVAudioPlayer will not download files from network.

Comment: So this means I need to use `AVPlayer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @paiv says, `AVAudioPlayer` won't download your file from the internet. `NSURL`s are used for local files as well as for internet resources, and in this case the sound must be a local file. You will need to download the file first, then play it. You will need to download the file (probably by using `NSURLSession` and and `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`) and then play the sound once the file download is complete.

### EDIT:

As @Sneak pointed out in his comment below, `AVPlayer` is able to stream audio from the web, although I've actually never used that feature myself.

Comment: Actually you can stream via AVPlayer :) not sure about what formats it supports tho

Comment: I guess I knew that, now that you mention it. I've removed that bit from my answer. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 0):

I used this before and it is working fine for me

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit